# End of lifetime of static object at block scope versus global scope

Tags: c++11, static, lifetime, raii

In this passage on program exit from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)

> If the completion of the constructor or dynamic initialization for thread-local or static object A was sequenced-before thread-local or static object B, the completion of the destruction of B is sequenced-before the start of the destruction of A

what is the meaning of "sequenced-before"?

In particular, for this program

```
struct Object {
  Object() {
  }
  ~Object() {
  }
};

Object a;

void f() {
  static Object b;
}

int main() {
  f();
}
```

is it safe to assume that `a.~Object()` is called *after* `b.~Object()` because `a.Object()` is called *before* `b.Object()`?

Comment: see also [this answer regarding sequenced-before relations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735#4183735) (and also the sequence *points* of yesteryear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the meaning of "sequenced-before"?

Objects are initialized at run time by the run time environment in a sequence. If initialization of one object comes before initialization of a second object, then the construction of the first object is "sequenced-before" construction of the second object.

> is it safe to assume that `a.~Object()` is called after `b.~Object()` because `a.Object()` is called before `b.Object()`?

If you can assume that `a.Object()` is called before `b.Object()`, then you can assume that `a.~Object()` is called after `b.~Object()`. However, that is not always the case. In your posted code that is true. But it is possible, in a more complex application, that `f()` is called before `a` is initialized.